# Edit suggestion rejected and edited

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I made this edit suggestion earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17707743

It was reviewed by someone and they decided to reject and edit it. To me, it looks like the new edit was almost same as mine:

1. My edit was primarily intended to make the image in the question inline.
2. I made a formatting change in an apparent output, but did not edit it further so as to not change meaning (OP remarked: 'long space and a null' so I did not remove additional spaces)

Is this acceptable? What would you suggest to avoid this kind of situation again?

Comment: And the reviewer actually edited back in the noisy _"thanks in advance! :)"_

Comment: @yivi Well, they forgot to edit it out as well.  They wouldn't have had to go out of their way to edit it back in for it to be there.

Comment: They did go a _bit_ out of their way, since they chose "reject and edit".

Comment: @yivi Sure, they felt that there was an important change missing (fixing the code snippet) and choose to reject the edit as a result, and when making the appropriate edit they simply forgot to edit the "thanks" at the end.  They didn't necessarily *go out of their way to add it back in*, more likely it's just a mistake that they forgot to remove it again when *the site itself* added it back in.

Comment: Actually, I think the "fixed" code snippet is wrong, since no longer shows the string of spaces the OP was trying to show. Awd didn't fix that properly, but at least trying to retain that. IMO, this was a case were a "improve" was probably more apropos than "reject". If they were going to click "reject & edit", they should be more careful and not reintroduce problems fixed by the original suggested edit.

Comment: When suggesting edits, please also check for proper capitalization and punctuation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You made a very good edit: formatting a code block, embedding an image, and removing fluff from the end. You *did* miss some spelling and grammar errors but given your question before my edits I don't blame you. 7/10, would approve.

As for acceptability? I personally disagree with the reviewer's actions, but they didn't technically break any rules. If you want, you can ask about it in the comments with an @reply, but keep in mind this reviewer's relative seniority over you.

On avoiding it in the future, I note that your edit summary was:

> formatting ...

Try to be more specific, for example:

> embedded image, removed unnecessary fluff, formatted code. The spacing before "null" seems to be intentional so I didn't remove it.